# How do you download ubuntu distribution for WSL offline install

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to setup WSL for ubuntu 20.04 windows app store disabled in my org for downloads. Can I get offline build for appx file?

I am getting below error:
Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF0, Package could not be opened.
error 0x8007000D: Opening the package from location Ubuntu.appx failed.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 61dcaa29-6a91-0005-bbef-dc61916ad701 in the Event Log or use
the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID 61dcaa29-6a91-0005-bbef-dc61916ad701
At line:1 char:1

- Add-AppxPackage .\Ubuntu.appx
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (C:\Dev\Ubuntu.appx:String) [Add-AppxPackage], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AddAppxPackageCommand
  ```

Comment: I dont know why my question was closed. Its mentioned that its related to h\w. I not yet understood how come it is related to h\w. WSL is a windows app with linux kernel stuff. I am asking for how offline kernel can be installed using any scripts. I am frequent user for stack and thought to put up a question by enrolling myself.
I constructive feedback on questions categorisation. Please reach user before closing question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are several scenarios in which you may not be able (or want) to,
> install WSL Linux distros via the Microsoft Store. Specifically, you
> may be running a Windows Server or Long-Term Servicing (LTSC) desktop
> OS SKU that doesn't support Microsoft Store, or your corporate network
> policies and/or admins to not permit Microsoft Store usage in your
> environment.

[This link may help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual)

Comment: Mine is a Windows 10 20H2 version. What I did was I downloaded distro using powershell invoke-weburl command and then installed Add-Appx command to configure.
Now I end up with No IP address in Ubuntu 20.04 version